# Reading a txt file and sending it to an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, text, readfile

I have a text file that looks like this

```
Words Words 
Words Words 
Words Words 
1    34.4e+1
2    34.3e+1 
3    34.2e+1
4    34.1e+1.... // and so on
```

I need to get the string number and concert it to decimal/double and then send it to an array where I can the use the array outside of the for loop to get the average via Enumerable.Chunk

```
decimal[] raw = new decimal[] { }; 
decimal[] rawAvgList = new decimal[] { };
decimal RawAvg = 0m;


try
{
   string bPath = aPath + "\\" + fileName.Name + "\\textfilename.txt";
   string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(bPath);
   readText = readText.Skip(3).ToArray();

   foreach (var line in readText)
   {
      raw = new decimal[] { Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(9).ToString(), style1) };

      for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1}", raw[i], i++);
      }

   }

   rawAvgList = raw.Chunk(20).Select(chunk => chunk.Average()).ToArray();
   RawAvg = rawAvgList.Average();
}
```

So for when I call the array outside of the loop it only grabs the last number in the text file. Am I calling the information wrong? I swear I have tried all the different way to call the numbers from the text file and I just keep running into errors. The error range from it not liking me using skip and substring at the same time or and enumerable error where it returned the error and not the number. Anything to help, Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend trying to avoid `SubString` if possible, since it will break once the first number grows to large, or if there are the wrong number of white space characters. Prefer `string.Split` instead, since this is less dependent on any specific alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the variable `raw` to a new value on each loop iteration, wiping out any value that was stored previously. The end result is that after the loop terminates, it will only contain the value from the last line in the file as you are seeing.

You can declare `raw` as a `List<decimal>` instead, then within the loop, you would do

```
raw.Add(Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(9).ToString(), style1));
```

This way, once the loop finishes, you'll have all the numbers and not just the last one.